# Why does my Postgres crosstab produce the error: 'Query-specified return tuple has 7 columns but crosstab returns 6'?

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I'm using Postgres 8.4.9 and having trouble getting their crosstab to work.

Here are what my data look like:

```
   rowname     |       bucket        | bucket_value 
----------------+---------------------+--------------
 CL100001 10011 | 1 A01 | 01/01/2001  | 14 16
 CL100001 10011 | 1 A01 | 01/01/2001  |  
 CL100001 10011 | 1 A01 | 01/01/2001  |  
 CL100001 10011 | 1 A01 | 01/01/2001  | 440 480
 CL100001 10011 | 1 A01 | 01/01/2001  | 475 475
 CL100002 10021 | 1 B01 | 01/01/2001  | 16 16
 CL100002 10021 | 1 B01 | 01/01/2001  |  
 CL100002 10021 | 1 B01 | 01/01/2001  |  
 CL100002 10021 | 1 B01 | 01/01/2001  | 440 480
 CL100002 10021 | 1 B01 | 01/01/2001  | 475 475
 CL100003 10030 | 1 C01 | 01/01/2001  | 14 16
 CL100003 10030 | 1 C01 | 01/01/2001  |  
 CL100003 10030 | 1 C01 | 01/01/2001  |  
 CL100003 10030 | 1 C01 | 01/01/2001  | 440 440
 CL100003 10030 | 1 C01 | 01/01/2001  | 475 475
```

...

This is selected from a table, ct, that is used to prepare the data.

Next, my query looks like

```
SELECT gtreport.* FROM crosstab('SELECT 
    rowname, 
    bucket,
    bucket_value
FROM
    ct  
ORDER BY 
    rowname, bucket',
'SELECT DISTINCT
    markername  
FROM 
    markers M,
    genotypes G,
    gsamples S,
    guploads U
WHERE 
    M.markerid=G.markers_id
    AND G.gsamples_id=S.id 
    AND S.guploads_id=U.id 
    AND ( U.ibg_study_id=15 AND U.ibg_project_id is NULL) 
ORDER BY 
    M.markername')
AS gtreport(
 labid text, 
 box_well_run_date text, 
 HTTLPR text, 
 Amelo text,
 Caspi text,
 DAT1 text,
 DRD4 text)
```

Which I've tried to construct following the Postgres documentation as well as I can. 
But this produces the error 
"Query-specified return tuple has 7 columns but crosstab returns 6."

Which is baffling. If anyone sees what I've done wrong, it would be much appreciated....

--Rick

Comment: How many rows does your second query (`select distinct markername ...`) produce?

Comment: need to clarify whats being returned in that second query for us...you give the make-up of ct but not markers.  Are you expecting 2 distinct values and only 2 distinct values to come back from the second query?  My preference on crosstabs is to create a select statement that joins the ID field to each of the 7 columns you want (creates 7 rows for each ID to populate the crosstab report) and then join this over to your other tables to populate the values as needed.

Comment: Apologies; here is what the second query returns:

markername 
------------
 5HTTLPR
 Amelo
 Caspi
 DAT1
 DRD4
(5 rows)

Comment: Hello @Twelfth, 


Apologies; here is what the second query returns:

markername 
------------
 5HTTLPR
 Amelo
 Caspi
 DAT1
 DRD4
(5 rows)

These are the 5 column headers specified in the AS gtreport clause. Not sure I understand how to construct your suggested answer...but which sounds like what I need...
thanks,
rixter

Comment: Hello @mu, 


Apologies; here is what the second query returns:

markername 
------------
 5HTTLPR
 Amelo
 Caspi
 DAT1
 DRD4
(5 rows)

These are the 5 column headers specified in the AS gtreport clause. 
Any suggestions appreciated...

thanks,
rixter

Comment: Hey everybody: nevermind! I figured this out. So easy when you know how! 'Rowname' just had to include everything that repeats, 'bucket' had to contain the column headers of the data, and 'bucket_value' just had to contain the data. Quite simple, really, my dear Watson...(!)

Comment: could you add this to the answers so I can upvote it and remove this from the list of unanswered questions?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `box_well_run_date` is not found in your result set.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT gtreport.* FROM crosstab('SELECT 
    rowname, 
    bucket,
    bucket_value
FROM
    ct  
ORDER BY 
    rowname, bucket',
'SELECT DISTINCT
    markername  
FROM 
    markers M,
    genotypes G,
    gsamples S,
    guploads U
WHERE 
    M.markerid=G.markers_id
    AND G.gsamples_id=S.id 
    AND S.guploads_id=U.id 
    AND ( U.ibg_study_id=15 AND U.ibg_project_id is NULL) 
ORDER BY 
    M.markername')
AS gtreport(
 labid text, 
 HTTLPR text, 
 Amelo text,
 Caspi text,
 DAT1 text,
 DRD4 text);
```